# Notepad++ tab color

Tags: colors, notepad++

Is there a way to change the color of a tab (in the tab bar) according to the path of the file?
I tried with the PythonScript plugin, but couldn't find a method to change the color of a tab.

I need this because I edit scripts from two environments at the same time, from a LIVE environment, and from a development environment, and I need to be extra careful when editing a LIVE file.

Answer (score 10):

I was looking for a programmatic way to change the color of the tabs, and reviewed the online documentation of Notepad++ but did not find anything about it. So, instead, I propose the following method for your case, it could be helpful to always know which of your files are from the development environment and which from the live environment:

1. Open a blank instance of Notepad++:
   [image: blank]
2. Now start a macro recording: Press **Start Recording** button on Notepad++ toolbar:
   [image: start]
3. Open a new document
   [image: new]
4. Now you'll have two open blank tabs.
   [image: 2 blank tabs]
   Right click newly open tab and click in option **Move to other view** from contextual menu
   [image: move to other view]
5. You'll have a window splitted vertically and your two tabs will be displayed next to each other. You'll use these two tabs as separated "containers" for your files
   [image: 2 containers]
6. Press **Stop Recording** button:
   [image: stop]
7. Save your just recorded macro:
   [image: save]
   assign a keyboard shortcut:
   [image: keyboard shortcut]
8. Now you can run that recorded macro (from Macro menu, or invoking keyboard shortcut you assigned), every time you want to work on your two environments.
   [image: run macro]
9. (Optional) Right click vertical separator between "containers" and click **Rotate to right**
   [image: rotate to right]
   Now your "containers" will be split horizontally and will be displayed one above the other. Personally, I'd recommend you this layout.
   [image: horizontal layout]
10. Click on the tab at first "container" and from there, open all your "dev" environment files; and analogously open all your "live" environment files from second "container". Note that currently selected container has a more intensely coloured active tab.
    [image: distributing environments]
11. If you notice that your working space is small, drag the separator to increase your current "container" size, but I recommend you not to take it completely towards the end, because it will make difficult to differentiate which of the two "containers" you are working on.
    [image: expand live]

Note: If you, mistakenly opened a file of an environment from the wrong "container" you'll always be able to fix that by dragging the tab and dropping it to the other "container":
[image: fixing mistake]

So you'll always keep control of what files must be on each container.
[image: fixed]

That's it. I hope this info will be helpful for you.

Comment: I like your idea. If I can put it on a script automatically triggered, then it's good enough (tm).

Answer (score 10):

About changing the color of the tab (not folder specific).

Notepad++ has a file called **stylers.xml**, located in the roaming folder or in the program folder. It also depends in the installation & windows version. If it does not exists then it is self generated.

At the very end of the file, it says

```
  <WidgetStyle name="Inactive tabs" styleID="0" fgColor="xxxxx" bgColor="xxxxxx" />
```

And here it is possible to change the color of the inactive tab.
However, it does not work, it is a bug that has been "fixed" countless of times in the past. To the date, the current version 6.2.3 UNICODE, changing the values does nothing.

So far, editing the stylers.xml:

6.2.3 = does nothing

[image: screenshot 6.2.3]
*design guideline, gray + gray = not good.*

6.2.0 = does nothing

**6.1.8 = works.**
[image: screenshot 6.1.8]
*Nice contrast*

6.1 = works.

5.9.8 = works.

5.7 = edit works.

ps: sadly,it is not possible to change the fonts of the tabs.

Comment: stylers.xml file is edited from within NotePad++ from Settings > Style Configurator...  You can search for and download some [color schemes](http://waher.net/archives/1013) that others have already created.

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\stylers.xml` . Other examples are in program files. Works in 8.5.6. I'm using this for more contrast: `<WidgetStyle name="Inactive tabs" styleID="0" fgColor="101010" bgColor="C0C0C0" />` From GUI it's in "global styles"

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add this as a comment, the button's not there.
You can solve your actual problem by using multiple instances of notepad++, refer [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Multiple_Instances). You can save different sessions and optionally use the "Open File In Solution (OFIS)" plug-in.

Comment: weird, I can see add comment to this answer but not to the question! :S

Comment: Using multiple instances doesn't look like a sensible solution. Even if I remembered to always open a file in the correct instance, how about opening a file from the explorer? And I can never be sure that I haven't made a mistake. And I'll have to juggle two windows, when the whole point of notepad++ is to use a single instance.

Answer (score -1):

I've if you've picked a different Style like 'Black Board', then you will have to change these setting in it's .XML in '/themes', and these setting are found at the bottom of the file.